# Inner SOQL Queries

Tags: soql, nested, inner, queries

I would like to know if there are any limitations to inner(nested) SOQL Queries.

The reason i am asking is that lately when i get a soql 101 error it leads me to queries that have multiple inner queries. Here is an example of what i mean below.

Is there a limit on the number of inner queries you should use or do you think that this is a safe way query for items. keep in mind that as you can see this spans over a number of objects and possibly a large unit of records as well. I hope this is clear and thank you for your help.

```
                SELECT
                        Id,
                        Name,
                        Termson__c,
                        Termin__c
                
                (
                        SELECT
                                Name
                        FROM jingles__r
                        WHERE Active__c = true
                ),
                (
                        SELECT
                                Id,
                                Name,
                                Code__c,
                                Status__c,
                                ate__c,
                                Start_Date__c
                        FROM Child
                        WHERE Status__c = 'Active'
                ),
                (
                        SELECT
                                Id
                        FROM squirels__r
                        WHERE (Status__c  = 'Approved' OR Status__c  = 'Awaiting Approval')
                )
                FROM Account
                WHERE Id = :accountId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit, looks like it's 3 times 100.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

I think it's a good way to get data, as long as the query doesn't get too slow to run.

Comment: awesome "In a SOQL query with parent-child relationship subqueries, each parent-child relationship counts as an extra query. These types of queries have a limit of three times the number for top-level queries. " thanks Packo_cz i bet thats exactly whats going on. i think this is getting called multiple times in a transaction as well.